# Set up SVN locally with File protocol

Tags: svn, configuration, local, ubuntu-10.04

I have referred the link https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/subversion.html to set up a n SVN repo for a project that I am developing right now. I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

I did as mentioned in the link provided and when I finally executed the below given command in the terminal

```
svn import /path/to/import/directory file:///path/to/repos/project
```

I got a screen whose picture has been attached with this. please have a look in to that and tell me what to do next. Thanks :)-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been put into the editor to write your commit message.

The commit message describes what your commit does.  For a commit like this I'd probably do something like "initial import"

You can provide the commit on the command line with `-m "initial import"` or by putting your message in a file and reference the file e.g. `-F svn.commit.tmp`

This is covered in this section of the svnbook:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.commit